# VIsual studio code intellisense stopped working after updating the application

Tags: visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I was using Visual studio code to work on my react project and suddenly i got notification as new update is available for visual studio code. **I updated the visual studio code and restarted the application**, But unfortunately the intellisense is not working with same project that I was working previously before I updated the visual studio code.

can anyone help me on how to overcome this issue, because I am very used to Intellisense.

Answer (score -1):

If you find IntelliSense has stopped working, the language service may not be running. Try restarting VS Code and this should solve the issue. If you are still missing IntelliSense features after installing a language extension, open an issue in the repository of the language extension.

By https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense